# Call RPG program from PHP

Tags: php, ibm-midrange, rpg

We have an AS/400 system. I am asked to look for a way to call RPG programs from PHP on our Apacher server. The only solution i found was installing zend server to AS/400 and using i5 PHP API Toolkit. Since I don't know how to use AS/400 and don't have access i haven't tried it yet.

We can connect to database and read, write from php. I am asking if there is any way to call a rpg program on our system from php code and send parameters, retrieve output.

I found there is JTOpen for Java. Maybe same thing for Php would work.

Comment: For clarification, you are currently running this PHP site on the i or is it on another system?

Comment: It is another machine. No php on the i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute host programs as if they were stored procedures.

For more information:
[iSeries Access ODBC: Stored Procedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzaik/rzaikodbcstoredproc.htm)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say but wanted to know the above information first.

Comment: Even taking PHP inside the IBM i, call stored procedures is very efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Something is wrong with odbc i think. Gives an error when i call the program. Trying to fix it.

Comment: A number of things could effect the program execution.  Take a look at the library list and parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Today the easiest answer is the open-source [PHP Toolkit for IBM i](http://www.alanseiden.com/toolkit/) that is shipped with Zend Server and also is available for free download.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iSeries developer so I can't give detailed instructions but it should be possible to use the CGIDEV2 library (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgidev2) to expose RPG functionality over HTTP. This would make your RPG functionality easily accessible to PHP and any other environment which can act as a web client. The caveat is that you need to make source level modifications to the RPG in question which may not suit your working arrangements.

Edit: Sorry, I just noticed that you said you didn't have access to the iSeries directly so this won't be a solution for you,